# CopyOnWriteArrayList implementation concern

Tags: java, collections

According to javadoc of [`CopyOnWritearrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html):

> A thread-safe variant of `ArrayList` *in which all mutative operations
>   (add, set, and so on) are implemented by making a fresh copy of the
>   underlying array*

but I want to know why its making the fresh copy each time as it is doing this operation in the exclusive lock.

Comment: I see no mention of locks in the javadocs. Are you sure it uses locks?

Comment: @Gábor Bakos you can see its implementation

Comment: Copy on Write is a common parallelisation technique. Reads are must faster but writes are slower. Everything is a trade off. The ConcurrentXXX classes are more balanced.

Answer (score 4):

Even if the list locks on mutative operations, one could still get an `Iterator` and loop over the collection, which is not synchronized. The fresh copy created by these mutative operations will not be seen by the iterator. This allows other threads to read from the list without worrying about exceptions due to modifications of the list, as mentioned in the Javadocs:

> The "snapshot" style iterator method uses a reference to the state of the array at the point that the iterator was created. This array never changes during the lifetime of the iterator, so interference is impossible and the iterator is guaranteed not to throw ConcurrentModificationException